# cat function not capturing full line of file

Tags: bash

In this bash script, I loop through a file to process each line (split into two variables), however when a line has a space or capital (there may be other causes), the output does not show the full line. Any help to get the full line instead of some cases where values are left out would be greatly appreciated.
Code:

```
for OUTPUT in $(cat path/to/inputfile)
do
echo "$OUTPUT"
cartridge=$(echo $OUTPUT | cut -d':' -f1)
cartridgeVersion=$(echo $OUTPUT | cut -d':' -f2)
echo 
done
```

Input File:

```
UPP:123
MCAS:123
PM:123
UI:123
GENSVC:123
CORESW:123
EFT INFRAS:123
EFT EP:123
ISO8583-IC:123
SSO-JAAS:123
UPP SWITCH:123
WBC-WSDLs-XSDs:123
PaymentInformationModel:123
IPF Baseline BSI:123
IP Business Pack Baseline:123
GESB-TLM-Endpoint:123
```

Output

```
UPP:123
MCAS:123
PM:123
UI:123
GENSVC:123
CORESW:123
EFT
INFRAS:123
EFT
EP:123
ISO8583-IC:123
SSO-JAAS:123
UPP
SWITCH:123
WBC-WSDLs-XSDs:123
PaymentInformationModel:123
IPF
Baseline
BSI:123
IP
Business
Pack
Baseline:123
GESB-TLM-Endpoint:123
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switch to `while IFS=":" read -r cartridge cartridgeVersion; do ...; done </path/to/inputfile`

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 0):

When you use `for OUTPUT in $(cat path/to/inputfile)`, word-splitting will occur on every individual word in the file, the concept of a "line" is lost. Instead:

```sh
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
  cartridge="${line%:*}"
  cartridgeVersion="${line##*:}"
  printf "\n'%s'  '%s'\n" "$cartridge" "$cartridgeVersion"
done < path/to/inputfile
```

That way each entire line is read into `line` and then parameter expansion is used to split the line on `':'`.

The parameter expansions that allow you to trim from the front and back of the string are:

```
    ${var#pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
    ${var##pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
    ${var%pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
    ${var%%pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```